# WebGL model simplification

Tags: html, 3d, webgl, game-engine, game-physics

I'm currently planning a Web GL game and am starting to make the models for it, I need to know if anyone knows if say my model is 1X scale, my camera zooms/pans out from the object and my models becomes 0.1X scale, what kind of simplification happens by the WGL engine to the models in view?

I.E if I use a triangle as an example, here is it at 1X scale
[image: triangle with many triangles inside at full scale]

And here is the triangle at 10% of the original size while keeping all complexity (sorry it's so faint)
[image: Triangle at 10% scale with many triangles inside]

While the triangle looks the same, the complexity isn't entirely necessary and could be simplified into perhaps into 4 triangles for performance.

I understand that WebGL is a state machine and perhaps nothing happens; the complexity of the model remains the same, regardless of scale or state but how do I resolve this for the best performance possible?

Since at 1X scale there could be only one or very few models in view but when zoomed to 0.1X scale there could be many hundreds. Meaning, if the complexity of the model is too high then performance takes a huge hit and the game becomes unresponsive/useless.

All advice is hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebGL doesn't simplify for you. You have to do it yourself.

Generally you compute the distance away from the camera depending on the distance display a different hand made model. Far away you display a low detail model, close up you display a high detail model. There are lots of ways to do this, which way you choose is up to you. For example

1. Use different high poly models close, low poly far away

   This is the easiest and most common method. The problem with this method is you often see popping when the engine switches from using the low poly model to the high poly model. The three.js sample linked in another answer uses this technique. It creates a LOD object who's job it is to decide which of N models to switch between. It's up to you to supply the models.
2. Use low-poly far away, fade in the high poly one over it. Once the high poly one is completely obscuring the low poly one stop drawing the low-poly.

   Grand Theft Auto uses this technique
3. Create low poly from high poly and morph between them using any number of techniques.

   For example.

   ```
    1----2----3----4            1--------------4
    |    |    |    |            |              |
    |    |    |    |            |              |       
    4----5----6----7            |              |
    |    |    |    |   <----->  |              |
    |    |    |    |            |              |
    8----9----10---11           |              |
    |    |    |    |            |              |
    |    |    |    |            |              |
    12---13---14---15           12-------------15
   ```

   Jak and Daxter and Crash Team Racing (old games) use the structure above.
    Far away only points 1,4,12,15 are used. Close up all 16 points are used.
    Points 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14 can be placed anywhere.
    Between the far and near distances all the points are morphed so the 16 point
    mesh becomes the 4 point mesh. If you play Jak and Daxter #1 or Ratchet and Clank #1
    you can see this morphing going on as you play. By the second version of those 
    games the artists got good at hiding the morphing.
4. Draw high poly up close, render high poly into a texture and draw a billboard in 
    the distance. Update the billboard slowly (ever N frames instead of every frame).
    This is a technique used for animated objects. It was used in Crash Team Racing 
    for the other racers when they are far away.

I'm sure there are many others. There are algorithms for tessellating in real time to auto generate low-poly from high or describing your models in some other form (b-splines, meta-balls, subdivision surfaces) and then generate some number of polygons. Whether they are fast enough and produce good enough results is up to you. *Most* AAA games, as far as I know, don't use them

Comment: I like suggestion 3, that's the one with the least modelling work ;) but I wonder about the textures applied, surely during the simplification I'd have to reapply the texture which is as expensive as redrawing the entire model at a simplified level? I can see the gain in simplification but not in addition to the complexity?

Comment: There are 3 render paths. 1. draw the low poly. 2. draw the high poly. 3. Draw the morph between low and high. During the morph both the low-poly and high-poly textures are used and cross faded. Honestly, unless you're shipping an AAA title or just want to do it I'd suggest use #1 for now and move on.

Answer (score 0):

Search for 'tessellation'.
With it you can add or subtract triangles from your mesh.

Tessellation is closely related to LOD objects (level-of-detail).

Scale factor is just coefficient that all vertices of the mesh are being multiplied with, and with scale you simply stretch your mesh along axis.

Take a look at this Three.js example:
http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_lod.html (WASD/mouse to move around)